# How to return value from iframe to main body with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a html code like this:

code inside file.htm

```
<a href="url" id="1">click me</a>
<a href="url" id="2">click me</a>
<a href="url" id="3">click me</a>
```

code in main body

```
<body>
    <iframe src="file.htm"></iframe> 
</body>

<script>
   function responseValue(val) { alert(val) }
</script>
```

I want to click `<a>` inside **`file.htm`** and return id of `<a>` to body.

How I do with JavaScript?

Comment: So, what's the problem? Attaching eventhandler to `a`s, getting reference to the main window or something else?

Comment: Try using window.parent from within the iframe.. you can call parent's  function using it .

Answer (score 1):

script in file.htm

```
var i;
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(i=0 ; i < els.length ; i++){
  els[i].addEventListener("click", window.top.responseValue(this.id), false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  Script In Main file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var frame = document.getElementById('myframe');
     frame.onload = function ()
     {
       frameClick()
     }
     function frameClick()
      {
    var anchorTags = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a");    
    for(i=0 ; i < anchorTags.length ; i++){
      anchorTags[i].onclick = function()
        {
          responseValue((this.id));
          return false;
        }
    }
      }
    function responseValue(value) {
     alert(value);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: if you are loading html form system folder it won't work in chrome..

put the files in server and check